# How can I get the row of a table added after pageload by javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-1.9

There are two "up" buttons in my html table; above one is from the definition and the bottom one is added by javascript. Please see the codes and jsfiddle demo below:

**Table:**

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>My Header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">
        <tr>
            <td>aaaaa</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input id='btnUp1' type='button' value='up' class='up'/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Javascript:**

```
window.onload = function () {
    var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody'),
        n, row, cell;
    for (n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
        row = tbody.insertRow();
        cell = row.insertCell();
        cell.innerHTML = Math.random();
    }
    row = tbody.insertRow(2);
    cell = row.insertCell();
    cell.innerHTML = "<input id='btnUp' type='button' value='up' onclick='NavigateUpDown(this);' />";
    $(".up").click(function () { console.log($(this));});
}

$(".up").click(function () { console.log('outsideload:' + $(this));});

function NavigateUpDown(object) {
         var count = $('table tr').length;    // count gridview rows length   
         var $row = $(this).parents('tr:first'); 
         console.log($row);
}
```

Please see the jsfiddle below for demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/Balkanlii/apdy34xg/6/

Please open the developer tools of the browser and observe the "console" tab while testing. You will see that when above "up" button is clicked, it returns a context via `$(".up").click(function () { console.log($(this));});` in the `window.onload`. However, It is not triggered when the other "up" button in third row is clicked since it is added by javascript after the window load.

[image]
I added `NavigateUpDown(object)` custom function to receive it, but the context of $row comes "undefined".

Using another line like: `$(".up").click(function () { console.log('outsideload:' + $(this));});` did not help as it is not triggered as well.

How can I get the row added by javascript after the page load, in javascript? Do we have something like window.afterload()? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace below lines of your code :

```
cell.innerHTML = "<input id='btnUp' type='button' value='up' onclick='NavigateUpDown(this);' />";
$(".up").click(function () { console.log($(this));});
```

with this one :

```
cell.innerHTML = "<input id='btnUp' type='button' value='up' class='up'/>";
$(document).on('click',".up",function () { console.log($(this));});
```

The `$(document).on` will trigger an event on any dynamic element.

try the same on http://jsfiddle.net/o6f705mu/2/

Comment: While the other answers are also working fine, I liked this one most as you don't need to use the dynamically created button's id. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody'), n, row, cell;
    for (n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
        row = tbody.insertRow();
        cell = row.insertCell();
        cell.innerHTML = Math.random();
    }
    row = tbody.insertRow(2);
    cell = row.insertCell();
    cell.innerHTML = "<input id='btnUp' type='button' value='up'  />";

    $(".up").click(function () { console.log($(this));});

        var button = document.getElementById("btnUp");
        button.addEventListener("click", function(event){
            var count = $('table tr').length;    // count gridview rows length   
            row = $(this).parents('tr:first'); 
            console.log(row);
        });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the onclick attribute from the input and directly bind an onclick like this

```
 cell.innerHTML = "<input id='btnUp' type='button' value='up' />";
$(".up").click(function () { console.log($(this));});
$("#btnUp").click(function () { console.log($(this));});
```

It should work

To add to this, if you then call your navigate function with "this", It should pass the button context and you can then use the passed "this" value.

```
window.onload = function () {
var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody'),
    n, row, cell;
for (n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
    row = tbody.insertRow();
    cell = row.insertCell();
    cell.innerHTML = Math.random();
}
row = tbody.insertRow(2);
cell = row.insertCell();
cell.innerHTML = "<input id='btnUp' type='button' value='up' />";
$(".up").click(function () { console.log($(this));});
$("#btnUp").click(function () { NavigateUpDown(this) });
}

function NavigateUpDown(object) {
         var count = $('table tr').length;    // count gridview rows length   
         var $row = $(object).parents('tr:first'); 
         console.log($row);
}
```